# My Drupal installed but none of the links are working

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, drupal

All the tabs "Content", "Structure", "Appearances", "Configuration", etc tabs are all sending me to a not found error. It is on "clean url", but it's not finding the page:

```
Not Found
The requested URL /drupal/admin/modules was not found on this server.
```

I have tried the many solutions on the web but nothing seems to work. My httpd.conf in apache has the AllowOverride All on

```
<Directory />
AllowOverride all
Options Includes
Require all denied
</Directory>
```

The structure of my folder is `C:\Sites\drupal`. The `.htaccess` file has `RewriteBase /drupal` uncommented. What else am I missing? I'm on PHP 7

Comment: My best guess is that it's because of you placed it in subfolder...URL starting with "drupal" is unusual.

Comment: Maybe you set virtual host wrong?

Comment: does it work if you do "?q=" pattern? Like /drupal/?q=admin/modules

Comment: @Paradoxetion nope, doesn't work, with that pattern I get a server error.

Answer (score 0):

Finally figured out the problem. It was just a matter of uncommenting aspects in the .htaccess. Both `# RewriteBase /drupal` should be left commented out, and `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]` should be uncommented. Somehow they were both reversed which caused a lot of confusion.